# Разместить базы mySQL в разных дисках (директориях) Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

Ubuntu 18 + mySQL 5.7
Как несколько баз данных mySQL разместить в разных физических дисках (или директориях) на сервере с Ubuntu?

Вопрос в догонку: ожидается ли повышение производительности, если берем в расчет только нагрузку на диск?

Comment: БД **всегда** располагается в @@datadir - это принципиально и неизменяемо. А вот tablespace отдельной таблицы (т.е. её тело) может располагаться вне каталога БД, в т.ч. и на другом томе. Местоположение задаётся при создании таблицы. Само собой, требуется @@file_per_table.

Comment: Т.е. надо прописывать отдельно пути к каждой таблице, а не к каждой базе?